# how-to install python3 using yum/epel-release on centos7

Tags: linux, centos, python, yum

I just found out that `yum install python36` on `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)` with `epel-release` installed

fails with

```
# yum install python36
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.copahost.com
 * epel: epel.besthosting.ua
 * extras: centos.intergenia.de
 * updates: ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
No package python36 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Could you please advise how to install `python36` using `yum` ?

PS. no `ius`, no `scl` releases please

Comment: just to make sure, you are on 64bit centos7?

Comment: yes, indeed,  Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64, Architecture: x86-64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just tried on my (same) distro, it worked, you may try commands below :

`yum clean all ; yum install python36`

Answer (score 0):

RHEL/CentOS 7 now includes python3 (version 3.6) in the base repositories.

```
yum install python3
```